# My foreach is not working

Tags: c#

In this code using `foreach`, even when I type an id which is not there in the list, it still goes ahead. Why is that happening, and how can I fix it?

```
foreach (Product item in listOfProducts)
{
    if (item.Id == id)
    {
        item.UnitInStocks = unitsInStocks;
        item.Price = price;
        Console.WriteLine("the product details has been changed");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    else
        Console.WriteLine("this product id does not exist");
    }
    break;
}
```

Comment: Show us how you read the ID. What does "it still goes ahead" mean exactly? Please describe what is happening, what it is supposed to do, and the steps you've taken to narrow down the problem. Where does `id` come from? What is `Product`? what type is `item.Id`? There are a lot of unknowns here and my magic screen program can't seem to see your computer.

Comment: Also please post code that somewhat looks correct - that  `break;` outside of any loop makes no sense in current code sample.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I was wondering the same thing. Its either a loop inside another or he missed a { after the else...

Comment: without a correct code sample we can't do anything to help.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are missing an open brace after the `else` keyword.
I'm assuming that was an error in you question rather than your code, since
as it currently stands, that code will not compile due to mismatched braces.

If you put in the missing brace, then you are `break`ing out of the `foreach` loop on the first iteration, whether the first product has matching id or not.

If you are set on using `foreach`, then you probably want something like:

```
var productFound = false;
foreach (Product item in listOfProducts)
{
    if (item.Id == id)
    {
        productFound = true;
        item.UnitInStocks = unitsInStocks;
        item.Price = price;
        Console.WriteLine("the product details has been changed");
        break;
    }    
}

if (!productFound)
{
    Console.WriteLine("this product id does not exist");
}
```

I'd prefer avoiding the `foreach` all together:

```
var product = listOfProducts.FirstOrDefault(prod => prod.Id == id);
if (product != null)
{
    product.UnitInStocks = unitsInStocks;
    product.Price = price;
    Console.WriteLine("the product details has been changed");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("this product id does not exist");
}
```

You'll need `using System.Linq;` at the top of your file to use `FirstOrDefault`.